# Where should I put the frontend server code in app created with create-react-app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, create-react-app

I created an app with `create-react-app` and I'd like to log something in its server console. How could I do this?

I've tried adding `index.js` to the root folder and creating `server` folder, but it doesn't work.

**Edit:** I don't mean the backend server here, but just the frontend server. I'd like to print something in the same console where I type `npm start`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly to do such a thing you should do `eject` your `create-react-app` otherwise you won't be able to modify the build scripts.

After the `eject` you can modify the webpack script or any other script you need to.

If you decide to do it, be careful because it will be more difficult to update your build dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

First, you cannot put your `backend` code in the frontend code. Because the backend code is run by `Node.JS` enabled server. But the front end code is run by your browser.

- All the react code will be bundled into one js file, which will be loaded by the browser. It will be simple JS files that renders views.
- When you see `localhost:3000` the server is given to you by default to VIEW and LOAD your front-end code. Most of the times it is webpack-dev-server.

The common options are:

1) If backend is REST/SOAP api then use XHR/ajax to hit the api. You just have to put the react generated JS file to your backend server's public folder. Also you can use completely different repos/codebases too in this approach.

2) You can use Server side rendering of sort where you put front end code in your backend views.

Comment: I don't mean backend, I just mean the frontend server. Is it possible to print something in the console where I type `npm start`?

Comment: @KarolSelak — Client side code can't log anything to the server log.

Comment: Just to clear things: I don't want the browser client code to print something in the server console, but I'm asking for the way of printing something in the frontend server console - the server serving all frontend files. It it's not possible to log things there - why?

Comment: I'd like to log something there at the moment of its start.